# J2ME - How to show root through the Canvas?

Tags: java-me, root

I want to show my root system in J2ME and show them through Canvas. I have used this code but not works:

```
Enumeration enumFiles = null;
try {
    enumFiles = FileSystemRegistry.listRoots();
    while (enumFiles.hasMoreElements()) {
        String fileName = (String)enumFiles.nextElement();
        g.setColor(0xffffff);
        g.drawString(fileName, 5, 10, Graphics.TOP|Graphics.LEFT);
    }
} catch (java.io.IOException ep) {}
```

I have 2 memory (C:/ and E:/), but the Canvas only showed drive E:/.. How to show all drives?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the while loop does find C:/ and E:/, then you are drawing them on top of each other, and that might look as if it's only drawing E:/

Try adding a y coordinate value for the drawString method.

```
Enumeration enumFiles = null;
int y = 10;
try {
    enumFiles = FileSystemRegistry.listRoots();
    while (enumFiles.hasMoreElements()) {
        String fileName = (String)enumFiles.nextElement();
        g.setColor(0xffffff);
        g.drawString(fileName, 5, y, Graphics.TOP|Graphics.LEFT);
        y += 20; // Go to next line
    }
} catch (java.io.IOException ep) {}
```